# Why there are so many /API/updateV2.php logs in nginx from AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: nginx, node.js, elastic-beanstalk

I have a nodeJS app deployed in AWS EB, the app does not have any http server (is just doing a background task), but EB is warning me every minute the requests are 100% with 5XX, and from the logs I can see a lot of entries like this:

---

### /var/log/nginx/error.log

> 2019/09/04 17:10:15 [error] 30256#0: *511 connect() failed (111:
>   Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   1.144.107.128, server: , request: "GET /API/updateV2.php?act=u&a=WtY0qEes9x0nhA6wsLwEm7hk&b=aB92DJgkwcpIo0BSLNBzyOJs&c=0&d=0&e=318&f=0&g=0&h=0&i=0&j=0&k=0&l=0&m=1&n=1&o=1&p=1",
>   upstream:
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8081/API/updateV2.php?act=u&a=WtY0qEes9x0nhA6wsLwEm7hk&b=aB92DJgkwcpIo0BSLNBzyOJs&c=0&d=0&e=318&f=0&g=0&h=0&i=0&j=0&k=0&l=0&m=1&n=1&o=1&p=1"

Why I'm receiving so many requests to /API/updateV2.php? I don't know what is that URL and my project is using NodeJS not PHP

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like someone might have the wrong IP / URL and is attempting to reach your server using said URL. You could set up a "tcpdump -i any port 80" to see who's trying to reach your server.

Worst case, set up ufw and add a firewall rule to block incoming traffic on port 80 / 443

Comment: I'm not a server admin, so not sure how to do that :( could be a problem if I just leave it as now? it looks like the request is every minute

Comment: One request per minute shouldn't have any impact whatsoever, so it's safe to assume than you can leave the config as is without any issues. You could still point out the situation to the sysadmin, maybe he wants to tighten security.